# Regex Valdation Pattern Required

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, design-patterns

Can anyone here tell me about creating this validation pattern?

all sentences start with a capital, the message ends with a full stop. there are no spelling mistakes.

Comment: Good luck on creating a regex that detects spelling mistakes.

Comment: yeah I have been looking for such pattern

Comment: There is none. RegEx can search for patterns. But to create a pattern that "finds" all spelling mistakes, would mean to know all "valid" words (find everything that is not one of them).

Comment: ^[A-Z]\.$ this will match the first two conditions but we cant spell check every words :/

Comment: `\M` matches words with a spelling mistake, and `\m` matches words without a spelling mistake. Just kidding. It'd be nice but how would this even be possible?

Comment: @JeremyThille if we want to match specific word spelling than how it would be?

Comment: There is a lot of logic behind checking spelling. HTML5 does it for you, with the [spellcheck](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_spellcheck.asp) attribute. If you want to go further and manipulate spellchecks with JS, you'll have either to develop your full solution yourself, or use a library like [nanospell](https://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JavaScript_Spell_Check_Function_Demo).

Comment: @JeremyThille well for now can u pls give me a pattern for all sentences start with a capital, the message ends with a full stop.

Comment: @artX already gave you the solution 5 messages above... :)

Comment: @JeremyThille But it's not working fine

Comment: Maybe `^[A-Z].+\.$` then? Any capital letter + any character n times (lazy) until it meets a period.

Comment: @JeremyThille It only checks first sentence upper letter but now the second sentence

Comment: @JeremyThille I want it should check like that    Hi How Are You. => this is true as u noticed that every beginning letter is in upper case

Answer (score 1):

This approach may not be fully robust for messy data entered from the web, as you will probably find lots of example text that doesn't meet your strict rules. You have foréign letters in your message. But here is some basic code:

Split text into sentences (using lookbehind assertion):

```
message = "A test. Not what I wanted."
sentences = message.split(/(?<=\.)\s*/)
                   .map(sentence => sentence.trim())
                   .filter(sentence => sentence)
;
// sentences = ["A test.", "Not what I wanted."]
```

All sentences start with a capital (plus optional whitespace). If a sentence has a missing period, then this tokenizer will treat both sentences as one.

```
is_all_capital = sentences
                 .map(sentence => sentence.match(/^\s*[A-Z]/))
                 .every(str => !!str)  // cast to boolean
;
```

Message ends with a full stop (plus optional whitespace)

```
is_end_period = !!message.match(/\.\s*$/);
```

There are no spelling mistakes.

NOTE: This will probably break because your dictionary is incomplete, your text corpus contains hyphen-ated words, doesn't contain apostrophes, or the tokenizer messes up on special characters or words with numbers.

```
dictionary = fs.readFileSync('dictionary.txt')
               .toLowerCase()
               .split('\n')
               .reduce((store,x) => ({ ...store, [str]: true }), {})
;
message_tokens = [ ...message.toLowerCase().matchAll(/[a-z]([\w-']*\w)*/g) ]
                 .filter(match => !!match)  
                 .map(match => match[0] )
;
// message_tokens = ["a", "test", "not", "what", "i", "wanted"]

is_spellchecked = message_tokens.every(token => !!dictionary[str])
```

If you are serious about spellchecking, you might want to research for specific spell-checking libraries